# Android Geocoding: Android Geocoder or Google Geocoding API or what else?

Tags: android, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I used both Geocoder and Google Geocoding API methods but I see that no one of them is 100% reliable.
Geocoder class in some cases, with Android 4, needs a reboot of the device.
Google Geocoding API at certain hours and with certain mobile operators returns OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.
What method do you use?
Are there others methods for geocoding?

Comment: Interesting that you haven't gotten any answers.  Also, the opinion part of this question is unnecessary.